# Storing different lists in csv file- not overwriting last addition

Tags: python

I am new to Python and somehow can't quite get this simple task to run.

I have generated a randomization of some images I would like to later present to each participant in my experiment. The randomization assigns each participant a particular order for a list of images to be presented. The randomization looks as follows:

```
all_images_face = ["01_1.jpg","02_1.jpg", "03_1.jpg", "04_1.jpg", "05_1.jpg", 
                   "06_1.jpg", "07_1.jpg", "08_1.jpg", "09_1.jpg","10_1.jpg"]
all_images_scene = ["01_2.jpg", "02_2.jpg", "03_2.jpg", "04_2.jpg", "05_2.jpg", 
                    "06_2.jpg", "07_2.jpg", "08_2.jpg", "09_1.jpg", "10_2.jpg]

ind_scene = range(len(all_images_scene))
len_scene = len(all_images_scene)

for p in range (0,participants): #for each participant
    rand_ind_face=random.sample(range(len(all_images_face)),len(all_images_face)/2) 
    TLS = []
    list_scene = [] 

    while True:
        for i in range(0,len_scene):
            print "loop round: ", i
            if ind_scene[i] not in rand_ind_face[:]: 
                el = ind_scene[i]
                TLS.append(el)
                list_scene.append(el)
                print "list_scene: ", list_scene
                print "TLS: ", TLS
            if len(TLS) == 0:
                EF = "Error"

    list_all = TLS + rand_ind_face # scenes + faces

    final_scene = [] # list to retrieve elements from index
    final_face = []

    for i in list_all[:len(all_images_face)/2]: # first half scenes
        all_images_scene[i]
        final_scene.append(all_images_scene[i])

    for i in list_all[len(all_images_face)/2:]: # second half faces
        all_images_face[i]
        final_face.append(all_images_face[i])

    str_all = final_scene + final_face
    print str_all 

# needed data
    random.shuffle(str_all) #shuffle order of scene/face of stimuli
    print str_all

# write the str_all into csv 
    fp = open('list_stim.csv','w')
    wr = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
    wr.writerow(str_all)

    if p == participants:
    fp.close()
```

I end up with, for example, a list that looks like this for p == 1:

```
str_all = ['01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg', 
           '07_2.jpg', '02_1.jpg', '05_2.jpg', '09_1.jpg', '03_1.jpg']
```

For each participant this random list of string names is different. I would like to store each new `str_all` list into a new row of the same cvs file, where each element corresponds to a column (meaning that each added row is for each new participant). I created manually with Excel a csv file called list_stim.csv.

This last code allows me to add my newly created `str_all` list, but when I run the loop again (for p == 2) it does not add the new list but overwrites the old one.

```
 # write the str_all into csv 
    fp = open('list_stim.csv','w')
    wr = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
    wr.writerow(str_all)
```

Comment: Does `str_all` contain the list of images for just one participant? If so, which variable contains the list of images for all participants?

Comment: Please be more specific: what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: Use json for this.

Comment: I have edited my last post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code pasted above, I cannot see any loop which iterates through the length `str_all`, as it can be seen you are calling `str_all[i]`.
The solution which I think should work for you is:

```
fp = open('list_stim.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
wr.writerow(str_all)
fp.close()
```

This will write the `str_all` into the CSV. Each item of the list `str_all` will be a column in the CSV file.

From the question, it seems you want to write multiple such lists.

So you will have to define a list which contains all this list. I am showing an example here:

```
str_all1=['01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '04_2.jpg','10_1.jpg']
str_all2=[ '10_1.jpg','01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg','03_1.jpg']
str_all3=['06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg','01_2.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg']
big_str = [str_all1,str_all2,str_all3]
fp = open('list_stim.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
for i in range(len(big_str)):
    wr.writerow(big_str[i])
fp.close()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

This is easily stored in a json-string-file. Here is an example of how:

```
import json
import os
import random

def func_returns_imagelist():
    # Do some magic here
    l = ['01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg', 
           '07_2.jpg', '02_1.jpg', '05_2.jpg', '09_1.jpg', '03_1.jpg']  
    random.shuffle(l)  
    return l

def open_database(s):
    # Load database if exist, else set d to empty dict
    if os.path.isfile(s):   
        with open(s) as f:
            return json.load(f)
    else:   
        return {}

def save_database(s,d):
    # Save to file
    with open(s, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d,f,indent=2)

def main():
    pathtofile = 'mydb.json'
    d = open_database(pathtofile)
    d['participant{}'.format(len(d)+1)] = func_returns_imagelist()
    save_database(pathtofile,d)

main()
```

---

1. This function will try to open a file called 'mydb.json' and return the data as a dictionary, if it doesn't exist it creates it.
2. It will add a participant with the function (func_returns_imagelist)
3. It will save back the file to json.

Try running this multiple times and you can see that the file ('mydb.json') is growing each time.